# Reference resources in javadoc

Tags: android, layout, resources, reference, javadoc

Is it possible to reference resource files (e.g. layout files) in javadoc? I could not find this in the developer docs.

Comment: in resource files (strings, arrays ...) the comments placed right before an element are reproduced in the R.java file (therefore you may use the javadoc from the R file), but I don't know for the layouts

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yup it is,

In your javadoc: `{@link com.yourApp.R.layout#layoutName}`

Comment: The link points to an integer value, not the xml file in the res folder.

Answer (score 7):

I've used **#**

```
{@link R.layout#dialog_player_info}
```

instead of a ***dot***

```
{@link R.layout.dialog_player_info}
```

And now it's all OK. Before I was getting this error in **Android Studio**

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'R.layout.dialog_player_info' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection points out unresolved references inside javadoc
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the whole process may involve

- creating a temp folder
- copy your source files into this temp folder
- copy your layout files into this folder ([possibly in a doc-files subfolder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/javadoc.html#unprocessed))
- running the Javadoc command from this temp folder