# How to reference an XML file in Android Javadoc?

Tags: android, javadoc, android-resources

Is there a way to use JavaDoc links to reference Android XML files in `res` folder.

Something like `{@link res/values/custom_strings.xml}`.

Comment: This would be _very_ useful.  Maybe the holidays are keeping people away.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
{@link com.yourApp.R.layout#layoutName}
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone else answered this question in another topic. Here's the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24814578/7262915

Hope this helps you!