# Is there a way to specify an XML file in block comments in Kotlin class?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, block-comments

I can't figure out a way to mention an XML file inside block comments in a Kotlin class. I know it is possible to tag a class or function but what about an XML file in an Android project.

Something like this where nav_graph.xml is the file to be tagged:

```
/**
 * For details check [nav_graph]
 */
```

Comment: You mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433645/how-to-reference-an-xml-file-in-android-javadoc

Comment: I tried the approaches mentioned but not working, unfortunately. There's no auto-complete and doesn't end up as a clickable link which is the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear on their official documentation that you can actually link XML/Resources. Just classes, functions, and variables. KDocs is a simpler in features compared to javadocs.

Comment: yeah seems like it.

Comment: If you feel this is the case can you mark my answer as correct please